# How to print different parts of a List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, printing

I want to know how to print a List in Java where in each position there is a String and an int.

```
List pasajeros = new ArrayList();
```

I insert the data like this:

```
public void insert(List a) {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name= sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        number= sc.nextInt();
        ClassName aero = new ClassName(name, number);
        a.add(aero);
    }
}
```

And it seems to work like this, but in the syso gives me an error.

Comment: `List<ClassName> pasajeros = new ArrayList<>();` don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: ***...but in the syso gives me an error.*** what error??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it prints this list.Aerolinea@154617c

Comment: then your problem is not at inserting, is at printing out the objects that that list is holding, in this case your foo class must override properly the toString method....

Answer (score 2):

So you have a list of `ClassName`.

To print them, you can simply use a for loop:

```
List<ClassName> pasajeros = new ArrayList<>();
// + insert elements
for (ClassName cn : pasajeros) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + cn.getName() + ", number: " + cn.getNumber());
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, using "public void see (List a){
     for (Classname cn : a) 
         System.out.println(a.getName()...);
}
and it underlines the a and getName saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Classname" and "The method getName() is undefined for the type List"

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an object without overriding the toString method..

***list.Aerolinea@154617c*** means you are printing the objects hashcode..
so your problem is not at inserting, is at printing out the objects that the list is holding, in this case your **Aerolinea** class must override properly the **toString** method.

something like:

```
class Aerolinea {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Aerolinea [nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like put method toString in your class...

```
public class Aerolinea {
String nombre;
.......
.......
public String toString() {
    return "nombre" = nombre;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it finally, it was silly...
I forgot to write < ClassName> in the method. Here is the final code

```
public void vertodo(List<Aerolinea> a) {
    for (Aerolinea cn : a) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + cn.name+ " ID: " + cn.id);
    }
}
```

since I had created it like `List pasajeros = new ArrayList();`, then I changed it to `List<Aerolinea> pasajeros = new ArrayList();`.

Although I can't write the final <> empty after ArrayList as some have recommended.